# What to include in a grad school reccomendation on behalf of my referee based on a course?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I'm required to draft a letter of recommendation on behalf of my referee. But I have only done a course under him and although I did really well in that course, I'm not sure what I can write in the draft.
I realize there's no way this would be a strong letter. But at this point I do not have another choice and have to go through with this. Any suggestions regarding the kind of content I can put in the letter are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this required? Seems odd. Or are you drafting a letter of recommendation for yourself that they will send?

Comment: @Buffy this is relatively common practice outside US and Europe as far as I understand.

Comment: @justauser, parts of it read like a student asking to write a recommendation letter for a professor.

Comment: @Buffy yes that does tend to happen sometimes unfortunately. Not good practice but professors here are often unwilling to write LoRs to the point where the student providing them a draft of the letter is common practice.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your instructor asked you to write a draft of the letter of recommendation that they then send out. That's a trick used by people asked to write references. When it comes to writing a letter of recommendation, you need to ask what the receiver wants to know. Therefore I would recommend:

(1) How does the instructor know the student? Because of a class with x students in it. What grade did the student get?

(2) Has the student displayed any attributes useful for graduate school. For example, was this a heavily mathematized class, or, was this a class with a big software project.

(3) How difficult is it to deal with the student? A student who asks insightful questions, ...

(4) What does the instructor thinks about the chances of success in a graduate program?

Nobody sane expects all letters of reference to be able to address all potential questions about the suitability of a student for further studies. Often, the fact that the letters were submitted is more important than what is in them (with obvious exceptions: "I do not know Ms. X very well, but to the best of my knowledge, she has never been convicted of a felony in the State of Wisconsin" would sink an application). Writing a letter of reference is dreary work, so somebody writing one that is not boiler plate is meaningful in itself. If it comes to scarce resources and an abundance of applicants, content of letters matter more. You did not talk about your field and your future alma mater, so I have no idea whether this is the case for you.

You can easily get admitted without a letter saying that it is expected that you will win the Fields medal, Turing price, and the Nobel price in at least two disciplines two weeks after graduation. Your recommender is not going to be sending out the draft you gave them and has hopefully done this a lot.